# Ubuntu 20.04 swap keys on apple magic keyboard of backticks and tilde sign

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, xmodmap

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 16.04 and noticed that the tilde and backticks key has been moved to the key to left of number 1(!) and underneath ESC (sorry, I googled for the name but didn't find anything). I am used to the old key mappings (muscle memory) so I would like to remap them back to what it was before so that when I press the key I get backticks and when I press SHIFT + the key I get ~. I've tried using `xmodmap -e "keycode kod = code"` but then SHIFT + key doesn't do anything, it seems to be broken. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You can remap keys in the kernel. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1375205/1524830

Comment: I'd probably be better off just write a bash script that swaps the keys for current shell and run it on boot